# Does .NET Framework 2.0 Support TLS1.1?

Tags: .net, ssl

While I am aware that .NET Framework 2.0 does not support TLS1.2, does it support TLS1.1?  I cannot seem to find the answer anywhere.  I know that you have to enable it on .NET 4.0 and 4.5 (and is enabled by default on 4.6) but I cannot seem to find documentation about the SSL versions that older .NET Frameworks support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### .NET doesn't care about different TLS versions

Any built-in .NET socket that requires TLS rely on the [SChannel API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380123(v=vs.85).aspx) in Windows, so the supported TLS version 100% depends on the version of the ***Windows*** operating system running on the target system, ***not .NET***.

According to this [MSDN article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2011/10/02/support-for-ssltls-protocols-on-windows/), TLS 1.1, 1.2 is available on Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2 and newer operating systems.

[image]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @HansPassant great resource, but newer versions (TLS 1.1 and 1.2) still won't work on platforms where the OS doesn't support it :\

Comment: That's rather obvious.  Maybe you want to avoid thinking about a .NET 2.0 app that runs on a later Windows version?  Who doesn't.

Comment: This is incorrect. You cannot negotiate a TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 in a .NET Framework 2.0 application regardless of the version of Windows you are on. See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.authentication.sslprotocols(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Looks like this answer is wrong. There are Framework updates to support TLS 1.2 as seen here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3154519/support-for-tls-system-default-versions-included-in-the-net-framework and also Net 4.5 must be installed to support TLS 1.2 on Net 4.0 applications as seen here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eee96d65-08b3-4c28-8c19-fe246824a637/is-it-possible-to-use-tls-12-in-net-framework-40